# What is the difference between "being in" and "being down"

Tags: word-choice, differences

I've come across both sentences and was wondering if there is any difference in their meaning. Here are the sentences where I met them:

To be down:

> Give me a call if you're down

To be in:

> Who's in for the show tonight?

Can one switch them without any impact as in `if you're in` and `who's down for` ?

Edit: a new challenger joins the list, `to be up to`:

> Tell me what you're up to

Also, I would point out that I've read/heard that in America and English is my second language.

Now the main question becomes: **Can we interchangeably use "*to be in for*", "*to be down with*" and "*to be up to*"** ? Can we also switch the extra words such as "to be in with", "to be down to", "to be up for" ? If you have any concrete example where one or another could be more appropriate/meaningful, please let us know!

Comment: Your first sentence means something completely different. I guess you forgot the last part. As it stands it means "pick up the phone if you feel depressed".

Comment: _Give me a call if you're in_ might be taken to mean _if you're at home_ or _if you're in the office_ depending on the circumstances.

Comment: _Give me a call if you're down_ can also have context-informed senses: down from Uni, down from Scotland, down from the Eiger ...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I would use _when_ instead of _if_. Using _if_ makes it sound as if you expect there is a good chance the person will _not_ come down from the Eiger.

Comment: @oerkelens So would I if that's what I meant. 'If' means something different. The first two are obvious ("Don't phone if term hasn't ended yet"; 'Don't phone if you're still in Scotland"; the third means "Phone if you've already got down, but don't worry if you don't get this voicemail for a few hours from now."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we interchangeably use "to be in for", "to be down with" and "to be up to" ?

"To be in for" and "to be down with" are more similar to each other than they are to "to be up to."

When I ask you, "Are you in for the show tonight?", I mean, "Are you **in the group of people who are going to** the show tonight?"

When I ask you, "Are you down for the show tonight?" that could be short for "Should I put your name **down on the (metaphorical) list** of people going to the show tonight?"

"To be up to" is used almost exclusively in the present tense. "What are you up to **right now**?" is much more common than "What will you be up to later tonight?"

"What are you up to?" should not be confused with "What are you up for?"

- "What are you up to?" = What are you doing right now?
- "What are you up for?" = What would you be interested in or what do you feel capable of doing?

Comment: Thanks, that's clear and perfect, I especially appreciate your effort of completing the sentences into how they could be rephrased, which definitely helps understanding them.

Answer (score 1):

You could substitute "around" for both "in" and "down" in your examples

However, "down" seems to imply that a person is unusually in the vicinity from elsewhere.  "in" implies a more specific location and also a sense of deliberate presence.  "down" is less specific about where exactly the subject is but is saying that they are in the area.

"up" is also used in the same way as "down", example

> next time you are up from London please let me know

Comment: I'd take "up from London" in this context to mean you were visiting somewhere outside London, but that's where you came from. To mean in London, "up in London" is used.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that, I've also added "up" in my initial question, but I feel like Mike's answer is closer to what I've met. Could you specify if you're British or American?

Answer (score 1):

In AmE, a slang use of these phrases implies *if you want to join or are agreeable*.  *Give me a call if you're down*, means *down with that*.  You might reply, *yeah, I'm down wih that*.  *To be in* is a little more *mature* way of saying this, but still slang.  I suspect it fits with *if you want to be counted in*.  It is possible that both of these invitations involved some reference to your current location making a difference, but i doubt it. For a better example see this urban dictionary definition [I'm down](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=i%27m%20down). I can't find this definition for *in* right now.  They do mean the same thing, though *down* is more *hip*, I think.  I suspect the person who asked if you are *down* is more "cool" and the one who asked if you are *in* is more conservative, mildly.  Thanks for this question, I like it!  Please forgive my use of mature and conservative, as they reflect my perspective and others may chose different adjectives to describe this.

I wouldn't use them totally interchangeably.  It is usually *down with something* and *in for something*.  Those two phrases can be used pretty interchangeably.

*Give me a call if you're in (for catching a show)!*

*Let me know if you're down with that!*

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful and closer to what I'm expecting. I like how you interprete the mood based on the chosen sentence, yet I've always thought "I'm in" was the most common thing with no connotation, since we even use it in my country.